# wpf KeyDown event and key combinations

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, keydown

I wrote a WPF application that basically loads the WebBrowser control in full screen mode.  It also disables certain keyboard shortcuts and right-mouse functionality.  All is working well aside from an issue with the KeyDown event.

Sequence of keys pressed seems to cause issues.  If I press Control key first, the keydown event will not recognize the C and L keys.  However, if I start with C then L and then Ctrl -- it works fine.

In order of keys pressed: 
**NOT WORKING:** LeftCtrl + C + L 
**WORKING:** C + L + LeftCtrl

Thoughts?

```
private List<Key> _pressed = new List<Key>();

private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (_pressed.Contains(e.Key)) return;
        _pressed.Add(e.Key);

    if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && _pressed.Contains(Key.C) && _pressed.Contains(Key.L))
    {
        _allowClose = true;
        this.Close();
        e.Handled = true;
    }            
}

private void Window_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
   _pressed.Remove(e.Key);
}
```

Comment: I've tested your code and it works as expected. Only thing I had to change was to comment out the lines `_allowClose = true;` and `this.Close();`. All button combinations worked.

Comment: @Ben interesting...  If I put a debug.writeline as the first line of the event code, it will not even show the key "C" being pressed if I push Ctrl first in the sequence.  But, as noted above, it'll write that I pressed C and L and Control if control is pressed last in sequence.  Ugh.  I'll play with it more.